# Как правильно построить запрос PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

В общем то задача такая: хочу взять данные из первой таблицы допустим `stud1` и поместить их в вторую `stud2` (таблицы одинаковые). Данные должны браться по определенным `id` для каждой таблицы, допустим у `stud1` это `id` = 1, а вставляем в `id` = 2. Пробовал сам написать, но не получается.

Также еще хочу узнать, почему мне выдает такую ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если я пишу так, все работает

```
select * from public."University";
```

Есть способ как-то это испавить, или так должно быть? Если это важно то я еще сопоставил связи между таблицами.

Comment: Если не указана schema базы данных, используется ``public``. Эта настройка в основном рекомендуется, когда в базе данных есть только один пользователь или несколько сотрудничающих пользователей. Пишите public и будет работать)

Comment: Начните с запроса типа ``insert into stud1 (StudName)
select StudName from stud2;``  Поле Id  объявлено, скорее всего, как счетчик таблицы - вставляется автоматически ``Id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY``